# Beginner Python: How to Reduce Number of Lists in and Optimize Following Program

Tags: performance, list, optimization, memory-management, python-2.7

I wrote the following program to generate all of the possible schedules I could have for the next three years (I'm on the quarter system) but it's ridiculously inefficient and, as written, wouldn't get me an answer in the next million years.

To clarify, I do have text files already written specifying the classes I'm interested in as well as the numbers, term, and year of each quarter (e.g. Quarter #1 Fall 2013-2014). I want to limit it to generate schedules with 4-5 classes a quarter, as is hopefully reflected in the program.

I know that any way I would write this would be very slow, given the size of the desired result, but if anyone could help me to speed it up somewhat, or at least give me an estimate of how long it will take to complete (24 hours or 24 months) I would be very appreciative.

Two problems which I've identified, but I don't know how to fix, are:

1. My compare function (converts a list to a set back to a list and then searches every member of a list for every member of another list)
2. The extensive use of lists in general, which according to my research are very memory-intensive (the combinations function I use, for example, produces an iterator object which should be more efficient according to my research than a list, but I don't know how to use the iterator effectively and thus how to reduce memory usage; also the 'GrandMasterLists' method I use towards the end of the program, combined with all of the double for loops and the linearly increasing number of calls of the compare function in each for loop, must also make this much more inefficient than it needs to be).

The following is very long (177 lines) (albeit also repetitive) but if you're looking for a challenge or if you're a programming expert I would be very indebted for your help.

(Also I realize that a lot of what I'm trying to do at each point might not be very transparent-- it was difficult for me at many points to try and come up with code that matches what I want to do-- so please ask me questions if you need clarification.)

```
import itertools

class Course:
    def __init__(self, NAME, TERM, YEAR):
        self.term=TERM
        self.year=YEAR
        self.name=NAME


class Quarter:
    def __init__(self, NUMBER, TERM, YEAR):
        self.term=TERM
        self.year=YEAR
        self.number=NUMBER

courselist=[]

def coursegen(NAME, TERM, YEAR):

    return Course(NAME, TERM, YEAR)

f=open('classlist.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    courselist.append(coursegen(line.rstrip().split(';')[0],line.rstrip().split(';')    [1].split(','),line.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))) 
f.close()       

def quartergen(NUMBER,TERM,YEAR):
    return Quarter(NUMBER,TERM,YEAR)

m=open('quarterlist.txt', 'r')

line1=m.readline()
line2=m.readline()
line3=m.readline()
line4=m.readline()
line5=m.readline()
line6=m.readline()
line7=m.readline()
line8=m.readline()
line9=m.readline()

Quarter1=quartergen(line1.rstrip().split(';')[0],line1.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line1.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter2=quartergen(line2.rstrip().split(';')[0],line2.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line2.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter3=quartergen(line3.rstrip().split(';')[0],line3.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line3.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter4=quartergen(line4.rstrip().split(';')[0],line4.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line4.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter5=quartergen(line5.rstrip().split(';')[0],line5.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line5.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter6=quartergen(line6.rstrip().split(';')[0],line6.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line6.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter7=quartergen(line7.rstrip().split(';')[0],line7.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line7.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter8=quartergen(line8.rstrip().split(';')[0],line8.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line8.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))
Quarter9=quartergen(line9.rstrip().split(';')[0],line9.rstrip().split(';')[1].split(','),line9.rstrip().split(';')[2].split(','))

m.close()   

def compare(x, y):

    if set(x).isdisjoint(set(y))==False:
    return True
else:
        return False

def offeredcoursegen(Quarter, courselist):
    offered=[]

    for course in courselist:

        if compare(course.year, Quarter.year)==True and compare(course.term, Quarter.term)==True:

            offered.append(course)

    return offered

def combo(x, courselist):   
    return list(itertools.combinations(offeredcoursegen(x,courselist), 4))+list(itertools.combinations(offeredcoursegen(x,courselist), 5))

Combo1=combo(Quarter1, courselist)

Combo2=combo(Quarter2, courselist)

Combo3=combo(Quarter3, courselist)

Combo4=combo(Quarter4, courselist)

Combo5=combo(Quarter5, courselist)

Combo6=combo(Quarter6, courselist)

Combo7=combo(Quarter7, courselist)

Combo8=combo(Quarter8, courselist)

Combo9=combo(Quarter9, courselist)

GrandMasterList=[]

for i in Combo1:
    for j in Combo2:
        if compare(i, j)==False:
            GrandMasterList.append([i,j])

GrandMasterList2=[]

for i in GrandMasterList:
    for j in Combo3:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList2.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList3=[]

for i in GrandMasterList2:
    for j in Combo4:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and    compare(i[2],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList3.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList4=[]

for i in GrandMasterList3:
    for j in Combo5:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and compare(i[2],j)==False and compare(i[3],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList4.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList5=[]

for i in GrandMasterList4:
    for j in Combo6:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and compare(i[2],j)==False and compare(i[3],j)==False and compare(i[4],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList5.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList6=[]

for i in GrandMasterList5:
    for j in Combo7:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and compare(i[2],j)==False and compare(i[3],j)==False and compare(i[4],j)==False and compare(i[5],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList6.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList7=[]

for i in GrandMasterList6:
    for j in Combo8:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and compare(i[2],j)==False and compare(i[3],j)==False and compare(i[4],j)==False and compare(i[5],j)==False and compare(i[6],j)==False:
            GrandMasterList7.append(i+[j])

GrandMasterList8=[]

for i in GrandMasterList7:
    for j in Combo9:
        if compare(i[0],j)==False and compare(i[1],j)==False and compare(i[2],j)==False and compare(i[3],j)==False and compare(i[4],j)==False and compare(i[5],j)==False and compare(i[6],j)==False and compare(i[7], j)==False:
            GrandMasterList8.append(i+[j])

for i in range(len(GrandMasterList8)):
    print 'Schedule %d \n' % (i)
    print 'Quarter 1'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][0])):
    print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][0][j].name)
print '\n Quarter 2'
for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][1])):
    print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][1][j].name)
print '\n Quarter 3'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][2])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][2][j].name)
print '\n Quarter 4'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][3])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][3][j].name)
    print '\n Quarter 5'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][4])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][4][j].name)
    print '\n Quarter 6'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][5])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][5][j].name)
    print '\n Quarter 7'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][6])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][6][j].name)
    print '\n Quarter 8'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][7])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][7][j].name)
    print '\n Quarter 9'
    for j in range(len(GrandMasterList8[i][8])):
        print '%s ' % (GrandMasterList8[i][8][j].name)
    print '\n \n \n'
```

Comment: Can we get an example of classlist.txt?  Also, assuming you are using python 2.x, your classes should be: `class Course(object):`.  Also, while lists aren't as memory efficient as iterators, it doesn't look to me like that is worth worrying about in this program.

Comment: I see a lot of redundancy in your code.

Comment: @Aditya Siriam


I agree. There were a lot of sections where I knew it would have been more efficient to write a function or a for loop but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. Also I'm bad at programming.

Comment: @Joshua D. Boyd  

An example of classlist.txt:  
GERMAN 209-0;S;13-14,14-15,15-16  

GERMAN 309-1;F;14-15,15-16,16-17  

GERMAN 309-2;W;14-15,15-16,16-17

Comment: In your python code above, is the indentation really correct in the final output section?

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd Oh no definitely not. All of the print statements following for loops are indented one, and for quarters 5-9 there isn't supposed to be an extra indent compared to quarters 1-4. Also there isn't supposed to be an extra indent after Quarter 3 and Quarter 4; I'm not sure how they got included while copying the program but that might have led to the problems with Quarters 5-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example data you post isn't long enough for it to take a long time.

You can profile your program by doing:

```
python2.6 -m cProfile ./your_program.py
```

which will tell you the number of times each function was called and a bunch of other statistics.

In your combo function, you take two iterators and convert them to lists to return the combined list.  If you rewrote combo to itself be an iterator, that might get you some gains.

Compare can be more simply written as:

```
def compare(x, y):
    return not set(x).isdisjoint(set(y))
```

Comment: I will definitely try that (-m cProfile ./programinquestion.py) in the future; it seems like a great way to target inefficient functions, etc. for optimizing any program.

Also thank you so much for the help with the compare function; I really need to improve my facility with Python's set tools so this will be a big help to me and will hopefully allow my program to run faster.

Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: In response to the size of the example data, the real file is 80+ lines (classes) long. Even if that's only 10-20 possible choices per quarter, it produces a very large number of results. I tried printing out the results for Combo1, for instance, and got approx. 96000 results for just the possible combinations of classes for the first (of nine quarters).

It definitely becomes more computationally reasonable if I limit the number of classes to consider for each quarter, as I've verified through direct testing, so hopefully I'll be able to limit the number options to only get reasonable results

Comment: In other words, I finally realized part of the problem isn't just that the program is too inefficient; it's also being tasked with handling too much data. I should be able to get this to work better by implementing your suggestions and by further limiting the number of possible schedules to consider.

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua D. Boyd
This isn't an answer, but I wasn't able to clearly format the example of classlist.txt in the comments for some reason.
Anyway, here's an example:

GERMAN 209-0;S;13-14,14-15,15-16
GERMAN 309-1;F;14-15,15-16,16-17
GERMAN 309-2;W;14-15,15-16,16-17
Real Analysis 1;F;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Real Analysis 2;W;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Real Analysis 3;S;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Organic Chemistry 1;F;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Organic Chemistry 2;W;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Organic Chemistry 3;S;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
Differential Geometry;F;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
STAT 383-0;W;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
ECON 381-1;W;13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17
MATH 325-0;W;13-14,15-16

etc.

Of course, the whole list is about 90 classes, which the program has to sort through to come up with about ten through twenty classes which are available each quarter, and then come up with all possible combinations of those classes for each quarter, and then combine the combinations from each quarter that don't overlap classes (ie so I don't get as a result schedules which include the same class more than once).

Here's quarterlist.txt in case this is also helpful:
1;F;13-14
2;W;13-14
3;S;13-14
4;F;14-15
5;W;14-15
6;S;14-15
7;F;15-16
8;W;15-16
9;S;15-16

I hope this is more helpful than what I had before. When I run the above program using the python compiler in the terminal, it takes a very long time to even return intermediate steps (I inserted several print lines throughout to check its progress and after ten minutes I only got the 'Combos'). Considering how long the preliminary steps take to complete, and that theoretically each 'GrandMasterList' would take progressively longer to compute than the last, at least the way I generate them, it seems as if this program would take an unreasonably long time to complete.

Mainly I'd like to come up with a more efficient:
compare function
method to generate 'GrandMasterList's (ie to combine all of the combinations of classes from each quarter so that there is no overlap in classes for each combination)

Comment: Also the above two problems are related since I use the compare function repeatedly to generate the GrandMasterLists

but the problem with it it is that it has to cycle through the entire list multiple times, once for each element in the other list, and that it is called an increasing number of times in each GrandMasterList.

So either I think I either need to make 'compare' more efficient  
or I need to use the existing function more efficiently, and I'm not sure about how to proceed going about either